# Intellij-Idea: Marking all files of unknown type be type: text (so that they are searchable)

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

Many of my scripts etc in intellij are marked with a question mark.  Then when I click on them them it prompts me:

> The file "bla" cannot be associated with a registered file type.  Please choose one:
>
> <insert table of file choices>

This would not matter **except** the files are not searchable (with ctrl-shift-n) until they are marked as text.  This is a major problem for me.  I have an enormous code base and I don't want to mark all of the unknown files as text.  Is there anyway that I can do that?

I have cross posted this to the [intellij forum](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5261013#5261013).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered [in the forum](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5261036#5261036):

> In Settings | File Types, you can specify wildcards for file names. You can associate * with the text file type, but this will probably cause some unexpected results when IDEA will start treating binary files as text. It's better to associate more specific wildcards if you can.
>
> Also note that Ctrl-Shift-N searches through all files, regardless of whether they are associated with a file type. It's Find in Files (Ctrl-Shift-F) that searches only through files of known filetypes.